# Mysql error code 1452 with two tables with different database engines

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I have two tables 'mm_ads' and 'mm_users'. 'mm_ads' uses the Myisam database engine, while 'mm_users' uses a InnoDb. From what I read it is impossible to create a foreign key reference in such a situation, becaues the latter engine is transactional and the first one is not. But when I run:

```
ALTER TABLE mm_ads ADD CONSTRAINT FK_76EC3E1DF132696E3358 FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES mm_users (id)
```

No error is shown, it reports the number of effected rows and nothing else. Than I see that the fk is not created just an index on the column in the table. As I studied the problem I found out that the engines of tables are different so I changed the engine of mm_ads to Innodb. But then when I run the command I get this error.

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`admin_pw`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-61b_3019e'>, CONSTRAINT `FK_76EC3E1DF132696E3358` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `mm_users` (`id`))
```

The types of userid and id are the same and I have values in the tables.

Comment: drop and add foreign key constrain once more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

**1. Drop The Foreign Key**

```
ALTER TABLE mm_ads DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_76EC3E1DF132696E3358`;
```

**2. Indentify Orphaned Rows In Child Table**

```
SELECT * FROM mm_ads when userid not in (select id from mm_users);
```

**3. Deal With Orphaned Rows In Child Table**

Delete rows from `mm_ads`? Insert rows into `mm_users`? Up to you here. Either way you must end up with no orphaned rows in `mm_ads` based on the `mm_ads.userid` > `mm_users.id` relationship.

**4. Change Engine**

```
ALTER TABLE mm_ads ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**5. Restore Foreign Key**

```
ALTER TABLE mm_ads ADD CONSTRAINT FK_76EC3E1DF132696E3358 FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES mm_users (id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was with the orphaned rows.